# How to use js for performance enhancement

Tags: javascript

Using javascript or jQuery how do I make images load only when the window size is greater than 998pixels so that my website doesn't waste valuable resource

Comment: This seems like the kind of thing you'd want to do with CSS media queries, not JavaScript.

Comment: @cdhowie yes I made the column disappear using CSS but the images still load in the background

Comment: You could use a media query to ensure the images had `display: none` set for smaller window sizes. I am unsure if this will prevent a request for their content, however.

Comment: @BenAston yes I did that but that doesn't stop the images from loading in the background

Comment: That's surprising, most modern browsers will only request the image resources it needs (At least on initial load). Could you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: Slightly different use case but you should also take a look to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

Answer (score 2):

Use [`window.matchMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) to react to changes in a CSS media query matching status:

```js
let img;
function addImage() {
  img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/100";
  document.body.append(img);
}

let mql = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 998px)');

if (mql.matches) {
  addImage();
} else {
  mql.addEventListener("change", () => {
    if (mql.matches) {
      addImage();
    } else {
      img.remove();
      img = undefined;
    }
  });
}
```

(Click on "Full page" to see the image appear and then "Close" to see it disappear.)

You don't need to remove it using JavaScript; you can use `display: none;`.

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments say, most people would do this by embedding a CSS with a `background-image` property inside a media selector like

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 998px) {
   body { background-image: url(bigimage.jpg); }
}
```

But, if you really want to do it in JavaScript, given that you're still working with CSS, just to at least set the background image, you could go

```
if (screen.width > 998) {
   document.body.style.background-image = 'url(bigimage.jpg)';
}
```

ADDENDUM:
And as the first comment to this answer points out, you actually wanted the window width so

```
if (window.innerWidth > 998) {
   document.body.style.background-image = 'url(bigimage.jpg)';
}
```

would be more appropriate.

Comment: They might want `window.innerWidth`.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

```
if (window.innerWidth > 998) {
   document.body.style.background-image = 'url(bigimage.jpg)';
}
```